# Javascript getElementByID().innerHTML() not working

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and for some reason I can't get the following code to work and it's driving me crazy!

It's

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="test" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="test" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
<p id="demo">something</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = "testttt";
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know the problem?

Comment: Your browser probably has a pretty good idea. That's why it reports errors.

Comment: Open up Chrome, hit F12 on your keyboard, click on the console tab. Error will be there in plain site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `getElementById`, where the last letter is lowercase:

```
----------------------.
                      v
document.getElementById("demo")
```

**N.B.** JavaScript is a case sensitive language.

Comment: Wow thank you so much it actually worked! Haha sorry I'm very new to JavaScript