# Why won't my HTML button run my JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

What's wrong with the following HTML? When the button is pressed, it should change to "test text".

#### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body id="test">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" onClick="test()">test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### script.js

```
function test(){
    document.getElementByID("test").innerHTML="test text";
}
```

Comment: Is the JS file on the same folder as this HTML document?

Comment: Besides `script.js`, check out the JS error console the next time. It would have output `TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function @ ...`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript getElementByID().innerHTML() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120534/javascript-getelementbyid-innerhtml-not-working)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not constructive and should be deleted its not gonna help in future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There seems to be a typo error. It should be as below:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="test text";
```

**EDIT:** You should check the point mentioned by Topro in the comments also. The script's src file name could also be an issue.

Comment: I don't see the difference between his code and yours?

Comment: ID != Id, now you see?

Comment: @IesusSonesson: the difference is the `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID`

Comment: well spotted. His IDE should prevent these kinds of errors

Comment: @andrew: and what IDE you use?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2, the problem is fixed. Typo error.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body id="test">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" onClick="test()">test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

In [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), code this:

```
function test() {
    alert("test");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="test text";
}
```

this can also done with jquery remove the event `onClick` like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="test">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">test</button>
    </body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("document alerted");
   $(".btn").click(function() {
      alert("click function alerted");
      $("#test").text("test text");
      /*OR*/
      $("#test").html("test text");
   });
});
```